# Вставка видео с youtuba на сайт

Tags: html, youtube-api

Подскажите, как можно выключить иконку субтитров, когда вставляю видео с ютуба на сайт через `<iframe>`?

Answer (score 1):

```
cc_load_policy=1
```

Пример:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/MS1JXkzVGxQ?cc_load_policy=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Живой пример: https://jsfiddle.net/5mxug2ao/

Comment: Все равно иконка субтитров отображается. (((

Comment: Ё-мое. Совсем не так прочитал ваш вопрос, получается. Выключить иконку, уверен, никак не получится. Даже не ясно зачем это может понадобиться.